# Circuit breaker open when uploading large file

Tags: microservices, spring-boot

I have an existing project with the following microservice architect. Client --> API Gateway(Spring cloud using Hystrix as circuit breaker) --> UploadService. When uploading small file(`POST /upload/video`) everything is fine. But when the file is larger then the upload time is very long and Hystrix will be OPEN and return fallback.

Does anyone have practice for my case or how can I set up the timeout for only `POST /upload/video` request on Hystrix?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you need to configure a larger timeout in the Hystric client;
in your example this is the "API Gateway (Spring cloud using Hystrix as circuit breaker)"

I imagine that your code will look something like this:

```
HystrixCommand.Setter yourHystrixCommand; ... blah your HystrixCommand

HystrixCommandProperties.Setter hystrixCommandPropertiesSetter = HystrixCommandProperties.Setter();
hystrixCommandPropertiesSetter.withExecutionTimeoutInMilliseconds(yourDesiredTimeoutValue);
yourHystrixCommand.andCommandPropertiesDefaults(commandProperties);
```

Here is an [introduction to Hystrix at Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/introduction-to-hystrix)

Edit:
"Hystrix Client" here means the client software that is using Hystrix.

Comment: When you say the "Hystrix client", do you mean that the command dynamically increases its own time out?